# The group of bijective maps $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ that move finitely many integers

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $G$ be the set of bijective maps $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ that move finitely many integers. Then $G$ is a group under the operation of function composition.

My question is, what is this group?

It seems to me that it's a group that contains infinitely (countably) many copies of $S_n$, for each $n$.

Is this accurate? Would that make $G$ a countable, nonabelian group?

[For reference, this is example 2.2.5 in Herstein's "Topics in Algebra".]

EDIT: yes, the maps are bijections.

Comment: By "map $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ which moves finitely many integers" do you mean a function $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ such that there exists a finite subset $X \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(X) = X$ and $f|_{\mathbb{Z} \setminus X} = \operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{Z} \setminus X}$?

Comment: @Mathmo123 The issue with that definition is that it doesn't force the map to be a bijection, so the set of all such maps doesn't form a group under composition.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Sorry, I forgot to include the condition that the maps are bijections.

Comment: @Junglemath Edited your question to add the word "bijective". Also, your thinking is correct. However, I don't know much else about that group, hope other people will provide more information.

Comment: This is called "finitary permutation (or symmetric) group". Yes, it is countable and nonabelian. These groups are reasonably well-studied. Just google "finitary permutation group"

Comment: One interesting property of this group is that, just like the finite symmetric groups, it has only one proper nontrival normal subgroup, which is the finitary alternating group on ${\mathbb Z}$, in wich all of the permutations are even.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This group definitely contains infinitely many copies of each $S_n$, as we can view the countably many sets
$$X_k = \{kn, kn+1,\cdots, kn+n-1 \}$$
and $G$ will act on this set as $S_n$ would.

Now this fact definitely implies that $G$ is nonabelian, but we still need to verify that it is countable.

To do this, we can note that since each $\sigma\in G$ moves only a finite number of integers, the integers moved by $\sigma$ will be included in some set $Z_N = \{a\in \mathbb{Z} : -N < a < N \}$ for sufficiently large $N$.

Since there are finitely many elements of $G$ which act only on each $Z_N$, we can thus write all the elements as a countable union of finite sets, and thus $G$ is countable. Formally, we'd write
$$G = \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty \{\sigma\in G : \sigma\mid_{\mathbb{Z}\setminus Z_n} = \text{id}_{\mathbb{Z}\setminus Z_n} \}$$
And since each set in the union is finite, $G$ is countable, thus verifying your claims!

Comment: May be a trivial question , but $G$ is defined by the elements of $G$ itself ? Isn't this circular if I am not mistaken?

Comment: It would be circular if I were trying to define $G$, but I am not defining $G$ here. Instead, I am showing it can be divided up into countably many finite subsets, and thus is itself a countable set.

Comment: @user710290 writing "$G=...$" doesn't mean that you're defining $G$. It means that two sets are equal. The definition of $G$ is already in your question, at this point one considers properties of $G$.

Comment: Should that $n$ in $S^n$ be a subscript?

Comment: Yep, fixed. Thanks!